# fast unitary matrix multiplication with block acceleration

Tags: algorithm, matlab, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Assume I have a very fast subroutine for fixed size unitary matrix multiplication. (The subroutine may involve hardware acceleration) Say, a function called `quantum_unmm_256(A, U, m)` right-multiplies a `m` by 256 matrix A with a 256 by 256 unitary matrix U.

Now I want multiply something with a unitary matrix whose size is multiples of 256, say, a 1280x1280 unitary matrix. **What would be a fast algorithm that make best use of the fast subroutine?**

All matrices are assumed dense, with 64 or 128 bit float complex type.

Comment: So `A` is still `(m,256)`, while `U` is now `(m1*256, m2*256)`?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at parallel matrix multiplication algorithms. You can always divide the matrix in blocks, and multiply it in pieces. You can even reduce the amount of operations needed.

For example, reading [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm):

[image]

Comment: The problem is, subblock of a unitary matrix may not be unitary.

Comment: @Kh40tiK I assume then you need to modify `quantum_unmm_256` to `quantum_unmm_1280`. If you have one, obtaining the second would be easy. Out of curiosity, when you mean fast, how fastis it? because MATLAB speeds are already very fast to me

Comment: You can assume the fast function does it almost instaneously, however only fixed size. In practice, the "fixed size" is much larger than 256, but still fixed and limited.

Comment: @Kh40tiK The fact that a subblock of a unitary matrix may not be unitary makes it very difficult to exploit that fast sub-routine, doesn't it?

Comment: @Kh40tiK out of curiosity, how long exactly? Because 2 random `256^2` square matrices take 2 milliseconds in my PC, and that is what I call "instantaneous"

Comment: Sorry, let me correct that. It takes 0.7 ms on average

Comment: Is there such a thing as a matrix-multiply algorithm that only holds for unitary matrices?  (Genuine question.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth We have a working O(n^2) `unmm ` algorithm for *reparameterized* unitary matrix. It's on GPU, which is where hardware limitation come from. So I seek a way to "decompose" large unitary matrix.

Comment: @Kh40tiK consider   `A=gpuarray(A);B=gpuarray(B)` `A*B`. Matlab is quite good for basic algebra operations on GPUs also. Again, I takes 0.7 miliseconds in the CPU , how fast can you pass memory to your GPU? Because with my experience, generally it takes longer than 0.7 milliseconds just to pass and return the memory

Answer (score -1):

This isn't a full answer, but too long for a comment:

It might be easier to work with a `(1280x1280)` if it were reshaped to `(4, 256, 4, 256)`, and then transposed to `(4,4,256,256)`.  But even that could require a `copy()` to ensure that the inner most blocks (numpy terms) are contiguous.

It could even be cast as a (4,4) object dtype array, where each element is your 'fast' unitary array.

I could elaborate on those actions if needed, but I suspect you have enough numpy skills to do it.

---

There are a lot things that are unclear about this question.

- why both MATLAB and numpy tags
- how is this block acceleration coded - if it's fast it must be compiled code; if so what's the proposed link to interpreted code
- what are the constraints on the data structure?  I suspect it must be some sort of contiguous block(s) of data. That's why I suggest the reshape and transpose.

Comment: It's unclear what reshaping has to do with block matrix multiplication...

Comment: Does the multiplication require that the block be contiguous?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The block acceleration *may involve hardware acceleration* so you can assume it's a O(1) algorithm, just not scalable due to hardware limitation. However the subblock of a unitary matrix **not** being unitary, so some really fancy mathematical trick would be needed.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate on what you mean by `unitary`.  That's not a routine concept for `numpy` or `MATLAB` coders.